# Under which conditions could a function analytic on a right half-plane be a unilateral Laplace transform of a function?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform

What are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a function holomorphic on a right half-plane to be a unilateral Laplace transform of ANY function, square integrable or not, for which the transform is defined? (As an improper Riemannian or Lebsegian integral or whatever)

If I'm correct, a function analytic on a right half-plane is the unilateral Laplace transform of an L2 function if and only if it's square integrable on every vertical strip in which it is analytic, with a finit limit superior as Re (s) -> +inf [When I can safely assume that a function is a Laplace transform of other function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44713/when-i-can-safely-assume-that-a-function-is-a-laplace-transform-of-other-functio) (check the comment sections)
But the inverse Laplace transform of (1/root (s), which is NOT square integrable) has a well-defined Laplace transform- 1/root (s)

Comment: Which theorem? Paley-Wiener? $1/\sqrt{s}$ is not square integrable on any vertical line, and it is the Laplace transform of $1/\sqrt{\pi t}$ which is also not square integrable.  So?  What exactly is the question?

Comment: I mean, what are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions for a function holomorphic on a right half-plane to be a unilateral Laplace transform of ANY function, square integrable or not, for which the transform is defined?

Comment: It depends if you say that $pv.(\frac{1}{t-1})1_{t > 0}$ is a function, or if you mean $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0, n \to 0} \int_{[\epsilon,n]} f(t) e^{-st}d\mu$